# excelJs currency format for Japanese Yen

Tags: javascript, formatting, currency, exceljs

For [excelJs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#styles) the *numFmt* works just fine for USD however can't figure out how to format the number for Japanese Yen.

USD format that works: *'$#,##0.00'*

```
// works just fine
//
style : {
    numFmt : '$#,##0.00'
}
```

Formats that I have tried for the Yen: *'¥#,##0.00'* / *'¥#,##0'* which have been unsuccessful

```
// doesn't work
//
style : {
    numFmt : '¥#,##0.00'
}

style : {
    numFmt : '¥#,##0'
}
```

I am always getting an error from within the spreadsheet that the data format could not be imported when attempting to format the cell for the Yen. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the ¥ symbol inside quotes for this to work.

```
style : {
    numFmt : '"¥"#,##0.00'
}

style : {
    numFmt : '"¥"#,##0'
}
```

See the text and spacing section in this [page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/number-format-codes-5026bbd6-04bc-48cd-bf33-80f18b4eae68) for a reference of the symbols you can use without using quotation marks.